# fastest data structure for retrieval info c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am Developping Client Application which is a simulator for TCP client may have to simulate 1000 client.

each client status info can be of the size 50 byte.The state info is required by the server and client simulator need to store some where.

Server can request any client about status info.So for this scenario I wanted to know which data structure can be useful.

Server is already implemented.How I can manage these Client status info.As I can't use boost and other third party lib i have to rely on c++ only.

About how the status information is managed:

- The simulated clients know their own status
- The simulated server can request the status from the simulated client.
- Each client will have fixed unique numer. The server is aware of this number. When the client is connected server will map the socket with this number to identify the client.
- Each time the server polls for any client's status, it will poll for all clients status.

Which STL/or Other data structure can used in this scenario.
Here no third lib party allowed.

please suggest me  which one is the optimum to use

Thanks

Comment: your post should be at least few times bigger, because we only have 20% information that we need to help you.

Comment: What's a client(1000)? How will the information be retrieved? Do you need to look it up in some way, or just iterate through it all? You don't give enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Please describe your problem better.

Comment: Sorry guys .Here I am Developping Client Application which is a simulator for TCp client may have to simulate 1000 client.state info which server may require need to be store some where.Server can request any client about status info.So for this scenario I wanted to know which data structure can be usefull.Here i worry about Client Simulator because server is already there.How I can manage these Client status info.As I can't use boost and other third party lib i have to rely on c++ only.

Comment: @Chris_vr: You can edit your question. So, edit it to put in the info you just gave in the comment. That information is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with it.

If it's just a simple lookup then use a stl::map (in STL this is typically implemented as a tree so you have O(lg N) lookup).

If there are only 1000 and you have some control over the identifier, why not use an array?  This will (obviously) give you O(1) access to any element given the key.  If the set of identifiers is all known up front, use [Perfect Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) and you can also get O(1) lookup.

To be honest, if you've only got 1000 elements, then pretty much anything will work pretty damn fast if it's not in a time-critical part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the **fastest is O(1)**, which is constant time lookup. How to achieve this and if it is possible is constrained by the specific context you have.

From your explaination so far, it's unclear what constraints you have (the server has) and we also don't know what information it has or how it operates.

**Open questions:**

- Who knows the status?
- Who knows about the status, both client and server?
- What does the server "have access to" before wanting to know a client's status?
- Does the server need all clients status every time?

A few examples when server wants to know the status of a client:

**Server has pointer to client object and status is on client.**

```
int status = client->getStatus();
```

**Server has id of client and status is stored in array. Client ids from 0-999.**

```
int status = clientStatus[clientId];
```

Both of the above are O(1).

If you describe things better, you will get better answers.

Comment: 1client know its own status 2. first client know and then server can request it to get it from client. 3. each client will have unique numer which is fixed.and server will aware of this number.when client is connected server will map the socket with this number to identify the client.4. Yes +

Comment: @Chris, please update your question with this information as well.

Comment: @Chris, what triggers the server to want to know the status and what determines the subset of clients it wants to query? (please update your question with this info)

Comment: @Chris, is the client id in the range of 0-999 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of a vector of user defined objects of type `<key, value>`, with O(1) access using hash functions.